# How to solve dependecies problems

Tags: dependencies

```
 ~$ sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

console-setup : Depends: keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu15.5) but 1.194ubuntu3 is installed
console-setup-linux : Depends: keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu15.5) but 1.194ubuntu3 is installed
initramfs-tools-core : Depends: initramfs-tools-bin (= 0.122ubuntu8.17) but 0.136ubuntu6.3 is installed
libdpkg-perl : Depends: dpkg (>= 1.18.11)
python-lazr.restfulclient : Depends: python-httplib2 but it is not installed
python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.5.1-3) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
          Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.5.1-3) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
python3-cairo : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.5.1-3 is installed  
python3-distutils : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8.2-0~) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
python3-gdbm : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8.2-0~) but 3.5.1-3 is installed  python3-lib2to3 : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8.2-0~) but 3.5.1-3 is installed  
python3-renderpm : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.5.1-3 is installed  python3-reportlab-accel : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.5.1-3 is installed

E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Comment: It's usually caused by the last package you installed, of course. What did you last install? Please provide a link to whatever instructions you followed to install it.

Comment: Did you try to remove python/python3 and reinstall it or downgrade/upgrade it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the very first error message...

```
console-setup : Depends: keyboard-configuration (= 1.108ubuntu15.5) but 1.194ubuntu3 is installed
```

...and let's look at those version numbers on https://packages.ubuntu.com

- 1.108ubuntu15.5 = xenial-updates (16.04)
- 1.194ubuntu3 = focal (20.04)

In other words, looks like you tried to install a package intended for a 16.04 onto your 20.04 system. That's a very bad idea, and it's not surprising that it broke your system.

Whatever you tried to install, uninstall it.

If you added any sources to install that incompatible package, remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Well thats true. I did not notice that script Iwas running is for 20.04 and Im running 16.04. But I have no idea how to uninstall it ))

Script is here: bash <(wget -qO- https://finnway.ru/downloads/sources)

Comment: Well, that explains why. 16.04 is not supported anymore and you risk rendering your system damaged / unresponsive beyond repair if you jump to 20.04 this way. It is strongly recommended that you backup your data and install a fresh copy of Ubuntu 20.04 if what you want is to upgrade Ubuntu. And please do not add response as an answer... update your question or comment instead.